# How can I prevent that the BackColor of a control is changed?

Tags: winforms, backcolor

I want a panel inheriting from a base panel to have a fixed `BackColor` no matter where it is used. My base panel looks like this:

```
public class MyPanel
{
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            base.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

The `BackColor` is not set in the `Designer.cs` file of an example form:

```
this.sampleControl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F,
    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, 
    System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.sampleControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.sampleControl.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
this.sampleControl.Name = "sampleControl";
this.sampleControl.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 0, 2, 2);
this.sampleControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(230, 100);
this.sampleControl.TabIndex = 1;
```

In fact there is no color set anywhere, so I suppose it somehow gets the property from the panel it is placed in. How can I prevent this?

Comment: What's the actual color you see?

Comment: The backcolor of the parent control i.e. if the parent panel is blue, this control will also be blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    private Color backColor = Color.Red;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        // Set the color once
        this.BackColor = backColor;
    }

    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            base.BackColor = backColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Is there no other way to do this, than to repeat all properties in the constructor?

Comment: @xsl Do you override other properties of the Panel?

Comment: Up to now only the foreground color. But there may be more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just set that in the MyPanel constructor.

```
BackColor=Color.Red;
```

You don't need the `override` unless you want to prevent others from changing it.

Comment: I want to control the backcolor property from one place, not everywhere the control is used.

Comment: All controls inheriting from MyPanel should have a fixed BackColor, no matter where they are used, without setting the property manually.